# dlopen and dylib : main application and dylib address space

Tags: macos, dylib, dlopen

My main application statically links to a static library A with a function ABC and my dynamic library xyz.dylib also statically links to the same static library A which has the same function ABC. The function ABC uses a globally defined variable.

Now when the main application Loads xyz.dylib using dlopen on runtime. The initializer gets called where i have called ABC function. This function ABC and uses the global variable from main application address space.

Comment: I have the same problem. I wish I could find a way to make the dylib self contained. This is a security problem also - since it means someone could create a dylib that you open with dlopen that then uses random golbal data structures in the main program.

Answer (score 0):

On Osx, functions which are inline the dylib linker will use the first one that is used. So for example, if an inline function is used in your main executable first, and then used in the loaded dylib, it will use the one in the main executable.

This is normally fine, unless your inline makes reference to a global symbol, in which case you are now be using one if your globals for both the dylib, and your executable.

Again this is usually fine, since the same version is used consistently.

The problem happens when you have 2 inline functions that reference a global that is in both executable and dylib, and one function gets used first in the executable, and another one used first in the dylib. Then you have a mismatched pair. For example:

```
class MagicAlloc
{
    void* Alloc()         { return gAlloc.get(); } 
    void  Free( void* v ) { gAlloc.free( v ); } 

    static RealAllocator gAlloc;
};
```

Suppose you call MagicAlloc::Alloc in the executable, then call it in the dylib, now for all allocations in both you will use the gAlloc in the executable. Then the first call to MagicAlloc::Free happens in the dylib. Then you will try to free something allocated in the binary on the globals from the dylib.

There are two solutions:

1. Don't use inlines to reference globals/statics. Move the global structure, and the function definitions into the same translation unit ( object file ). Mark the globals "static" so they aren't even visible outside the TLU. Now your functions will be resolved statically in the link step, and bound to the right global.
2. Hide all the symbols in the executable except the plugin api. Link as normal, but when linking the binary itself pass the following to the linker:

   -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,export_file

Where export file is a list of link symbols that should be exported. E.g. you will need to at least have "_main" in that file. Now when your dylib runs it won't be able to dynamically link to the wrong inlines, because they won't be in the dynamic symbol table. The second solution is also more secure, since a malicious plugin won't be able to access globals as easily.